# Pygame catching Enter Button

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, pygame

I am trying to catch Enter button with pygame, not Enter button on keypad, which I want is the Enter button under Backspace button. They are not same, because when I catch Enter button on keypad, other Enter button is not working.

> http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html

There is a documentation about keys, but there is only keypad Enter button. I tried these codes:

> This working for keypad Enter button, but other Enter button is not
>   working:

```
if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key==pygame.K_KP_ENTER:
        #some codes
```

> I tried to catch another Enter button with these codes(hopeless):

```
if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key==pygame.K_ENTER:
        #some codes
```

But of course an error appears:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'K_ENTER'
```

Couldn't figure out how to catch Enter button under Backspace.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think you want K_RETURN , as the enter key under the backspace is sometimes referred to as "carriage return", from old typewriter lingo.

Comment: Excatly, thanks for answer. But in documentation, its mentioned as _K_RETURN      \r      return_ , why?

Comment: \r is the escape representation for carriage return,  ord("\r")=10, where \n is the escape representation for newline, ord("\n")=13

Comment: Got it, well better if they put a string like "Its also Enter key!"

Answer (score 5):

According to pygame.org, K_KP_ENTER ->  is Key Pad Enter ||K_RETURN -> basic enter key

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
   if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
       if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:    
           #Your code here
```

[Here is all the key words in pygame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ubtsf.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

In my environment(python 3.8.3, Windows 10), `K_RETURN` enum worked!

```py
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
        # some codes
```